# atribuir valor radio que se encontra no sql - Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Pretendo que o utilizador ao carregar a pagina do update de dados consiga ver os dados que introduziu no seu registo. Consigo que apareça os dados que estão no type=text mas não no tipo=radio.

View:

```
<?php foreach ($resultados_pesquisa as $linha) {
   $nome = $linha["NOME"];
   $genero $linha["GENERO"];
   ?>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('Menu');?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
          <h3>Dados pessoais</h3>

<!-- Nome -->
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php   echo $nome  ?>" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nome"> 
          </div>

<!-- Genero -->
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputGenero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Genero</label>
     <label id="masculino">
     <input type="radio" name="genero" value="masculino">Masculino
     </label>
     <label id="feminino">
     <input type="radio" name="genero" value="feminino">Feminino
     </label>
   </div>

</form>
 <?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio"
                <?php if (isset($genero) && $genero=="masculino") echo "checked";?>
                 name="genero" value="masculino"> Masculino
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução que você poderia aplicar, seria utilizando uma expressão booleana dentro do radio, para definir se o radio estará checado ou não, como segue no exemplo abaixo, onde para que ele possa funcionar a variável `$genero` tem que ser do tipo `Boolean` (true ou false):

**Usando operador ternário:**

```
<input type="radio" <?php echo $genero ? 'checked': ''; ?>
```

**Usando a `if` de uma linha:**

```
<input type="radio" <?php if ($genero) echo 'checked'; ?>
```

No seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputGenero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Genero</label>
     <label id="masculino">
     <input type="radio" <?php echo $genero ? 'checked': ''; ?> name="genero" value="masculino">Masculino
     </label>
     <label id="feminino">
     <input type="radio" <?php echo $genero ? 'checked': ''; ?> name="genero" value="feminino">Feminino
     </label>
   </div>
```

Comment: Não resultou, mas já descobri. Obrigado